# Appending an numeric value at the and of String

Tags: sql, c, odbc, printf

i am trying to insert multiple insert in table. For that i have created an int column table and inserting using for loop function but i am not able to write proper code which i want to do.
i Need some thing like that

```
for(i=0;i<1800;i++)
{

    retcode =  SQLPrepare(hstmt,(SQLCHAR *)"insert into dbo.vivtest values(i)",SQL_NTS);
    if (retcode != SQL_SUCCESS)
        {
            printf("Error in SQLPrepare - insert\n");
            odbc_Error(henv,hdbc,hstmt);
            getch();
        }
    else
        printf("Successfull execution of  %d th  Prepare\n",i);
```

It's giving me error every time.

Answer (score 4):

The following is a useful link about `SQLPrepare()` and how to bind parameters. Binding parameters is a safe way of inserting variable contents into your SQL strings and also a prepared statement made in this way is an efficient way of executing a statement multiple times.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms716365(v=vs.85).aspx

It gives an example of binding parameters to an SQL query. The give the following example:

```
SQLPrepare(hstmt, "UPDATE Parts SET Price = ? WHERE PartID = ?", SQL_NTS);
```

In the SQL string you can see a few `?` (question marks). These are like placeholders in the SQL string which you can then "bind parameters to" (i.e., substitute in a variable contents in place of).

To continue the MSDN example...

```
SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_FLOAT, SQL_REAL, 7, 0,
                  &Price, 0, &PriceInd);
SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 2, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_ULONG, SQL_INTEGER, 10, 0,
                  &PartID, 0, &PartIDInd);
```

The first statement replaces the first question mark with a floating point value from the variable `Price` and the second bind replaces the second question mark with an integer from the `PartID` variable.

Your prepare statement should probably looks something like...

```
SQLINTEGER    iInd;
SQLUINTEGER   i;
...
...
retcode =  SQLPrepare(hstmt,(SQLCHAR *)"insert into dbo.vivtest values(?)",SQL_NTS);
...
...
SQLBindParameter(hstmt, 1, SQL_PARAM_INPUT, SQL_C_ULONG, SQL_INTEGER, 10, 0,
              &i, 0, &iInd);
```

Comment: +1 The practice of using param binding cannot be over-stated. Your SQL-injection avoidance ratio will thank you later.

Answer (score 3):

You should use either [SQL Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms710963%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), or `sprintf()`.

**Preferably the former.**

Comment: *(facepalms)* I should not have mentioned sprintf().